# redux not catching errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-redux

So whenever the app is loaded it should check for user Auth using the `loadUser()`, the problem I'm having is that if there is no token in localStorage, the server won't return any errors(when its suppose to). I looked at the code for auth(backend), and it returns a status meassage when no token received, I was wondering is it because no token isn't a type of error, that's way the server didn't send an error response?

Below are the code snippets:

auth.js(backend)

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const config = require("config");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  //get token from header
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  // check if not token


  
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "no token, auth denied" });
  }
  
  //verify token

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"));
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
      msg: "token isnt valid",
    });
  }
};
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
      store.dispatch(loadUser());
    }
  }, []);
```

auth.js Redux

```
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("from auth.js");
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");
    console.log("inside auth.js get auth route");
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error from auth.js");
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

Basically the code inside `catch(err) { //code }` 
is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me, added else condition into App.js solved the issue.